# Debugging Arduino Due in Visual Studio Code using Atmel-Ice

Tags: visual-studio-code, atmel, arduino-due

I'm trying to figure out which external hardware debuggers are compatible with Visual Studio Code and JTAG.
I was looking at the Atmel-Ice but it's not clear if this can integrate with Visual Studio Code.

Any tips to get me started?

Thanks

-John

Comment: What was the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using PlatformIO. I've used it on a number of projects and is a VSCode extension.

I haven't used my ICE outside of ATMEL Studio but am going to cut to cord as it were. There are people who use the JTAG interface for debugging:
https://community.platformio.org/t/getting-started-with-debugging/19361

You can also use [Serial Wire Debug](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/cpu-architecture/debug-visibility-and-trace/coresight-architecture/serial-wire-debug) (SWD) see
https://medium.com/@manuel.bl/arduino-in-circuit-debugging-with-platformio-9f699da57ddc for more details.

I'm going to give both a shot in my current project. Again, SWD will only work with the 32 bit chips not the standard 8bit ones we are used to in the older Arduinos.